# Trying to run current script again causes stack overflow or parserror?

Tags: python, reflection, subprocess, metaprogramming, python-ast

I'm writing a script that will modify the code in the script and rerun it automatically but whichever way I do it, it always goes into repeated output until the kernel restarts and if I keyboard interrupt sometimes I get: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'.
And usually this is a Pandas error, but there's no Pandas.
Ideally, I would like to accomplish this without using shell and also be able to set a breakpoint so instead of accessing the current file I can just access everything written up until that point.
This is every way I've tried it. I think maybe if there was a way to do introspection from a context manager (like if there is a way to access an object from yield) that would be great to know.

```
    current_file = clear_me()
    code_to_be = "".join(rf"{e}" for e in current_file)
    #str(clear_me()).strip('[]')
    import parser
    xyyx = parser.suite(code_to_be)
    exec(xyyx.compile())
    
    import os
    
    # path_to_script = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    # my_filename = os.path.join(path_to_script, "my_file.py")
    
    # with open(my_filename, "w") as handle:
    #     print(code_to_be, file=handle)
    
    #exec(compile(code_to_be, "<string>", "exec"))
    
    import subprocess
    #subprocess.run(["python", f"{__file__}"])
    #exec(open("my_file.py").read())
```

```
def clear_me():
    f = open(rf"{__file__}", 'r')
    takethel = f.readlines()
    return takethel
```

Comment: (1) What is `dello`? (2) Do you run this in a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to change the var names from nonsense. So dello = code_to_be. It's from file.read_lines() converted back into a string. And no, I'm using Spyder IDE.

Comment: Assuming that both code snippets are actually in one file, the code loads and executes itself which loads and executes itself which... and so on until stack or memory overflow.

Comment: Yeah I haven't tried using file.close with a context manager because it would just reopen and close still. When I wrote it, I was hoping it would just write/read itself once and exit. I would rather not access the file itself, I think the solution has something to do with AST but I still don't know how I would get something to work like a breakpoint (read all the code up until a certain point) -- well, without altering the code before it because I know I could just wrap everything as a string and then compile but that's not what I want.

Comment: `exec` allows to specify a global dictionary. You can add a variable in it so that the code can check for the existence of the variable to know if code is executed inside the `exec` call or regularly outside of `exec` and react accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tentative solution based on Michael Butscher's suggestions. It works to prevent the stack overflow, which was the point of the question. But I don't yet if I'll be able to rewrite the script how I wanted yet.
And for extra detail, using the suite object's compile method as the object argument for exec gave me TypeError: <module 'builtins' (built-in)> is a built-in module. That's why I changed it.

```
    current_file = clear_me()
    global_env = {"fun": True}
    local_env = {}
    code_to_be = str(clear_me()).strip('[]')
    this_script = compile(code_to_be, "<string>", "exec")
    try:
        globals()["fun"]
    except KeyError:
        exec(this_script, global_env, local_env)
```